# Component Link Caching Not Working?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

We seem to have a problem with component link caching. Our log files show the following messages:

> 2013-06-26 14:22:58 WARN  ComponentLink:144 - Object cache is enabled
>   but LinkInfo or PageMeta Home objects arent in the CacheBindings,
>   ComponentLink caching will not be enabled
>
> 2013-06-26 14:22:58 WARN  PageLink:97 - Object cache is enabled but
>   PageMeta Home object isnt in the CacheBindings, PageLink caching will
>   not be enabled

As far as I know all home interfaces are replaced by Data Access Object ([DAO](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html)) in 2011 and there is no `CacheBindings` section in the `cd_storage_conf.xml`.

As we need to build a high-performance site, caching is very important. Does anyone know if this is a real issue and possibly know how to fix this?

Many thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 5):

I've seen this happening a lot on Experience Manager enabled sites; something in the setup there forces componentLinking to never use caching. Alternatively, it might be the "LinkInfo" Item typeMapping which is set to not be cached ...

Comment: Hi Rogier, it seems you're right about eXperience Manager, forgot to mention that in my original post. I turned it off and now I see the CacheController creating dependencies for the components. The warning messages are also gone as well. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - be sure not to enable the experience manager on your live site too :)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the ItemType bindings in cd_storage_conf, you'll see an Attribute `cached="true|false"` for each binding.

This allows you to control which item types should be cached, and which ones shouldn't. The warning you're getting is just informing you that Tridion didn't find a `cache="true"` for linking.

If you're anywhere near sane, you do not have all your ItemType bindings in the cd_storage_conf, instead you'll have something along these lines:

```
<ItemTypes defaultStorageId="sqlserver" cached="false">
    <Item typeMapping="Page" cached="false" storageId="filesystem" />
    <Item typeMapping="Binary" cached="false" storageId="filesystem" />
</ItemTypes>
```

the `cached="false"` attribute of the `ItemTypes` element is the default setting for all Item types, including those that are not declared explicitly.

Setting that attribute to true will basically enable cache for all Item types - except for those that, as in my example for Page & Binary, have `cached="false"`

Comment: "Near sane?" I thought just configuring the differences was the creatively lazy... I mean **smart and effective** approach. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The solution is nicely explained by Nuno but you also have a shortcut. Just enable caching for metadata itemType. In 2011SP1 you can have in your storage config:

```
<Item typeMapping="Metadata" cached="true" storageId="...."/>
```

In 2011 you need to manually specify the types you want to cache:

```
<Item typeMapping="PageMeta" cached="true" storageId="...."/>
<Item typeMapping="ComponentMeta" cached="true" storageId="...."/>
<Item typeMapping="LinkInfo" cached="true" storageId="...."/>
```

Hope this helps.